# Someone is trying to access my Facebook account

Tags: security

So I just received a text message from Facebook that someone is trying to reset my Facebook password. Is there any possible way to track this person out or gather any information about him?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Close your public profile.

This kind of attempt could be ended on a identity theft.

Keep your data safe.

Comment: By  closing my public profile do you mean deleting my Facebook account can you explain what do you mean and give the steps if possble